# Access ODBC Query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to run a query that will retrieve data from a SQL Server database. The problem is that after running the macro, it requires that I insert a username and password to access the database.

Just wondering if there is any way that I can bypass the credentials through VBA (possibly creating some sort of connection and passing a connect string). I understand I can create a pass-through query with the Query Design builder, but is there any way to pass in the credentials as a separate parameter in VBA when calling a query.

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryName", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I've done this by destroying and creating the pass-through query. Here's some code used for Oracle but it will work for SQL Server. Just make sure that you have a DSN that matches:

```
Dim db As Database, q As QueryDef, sqlString as string

Set db = CurrentDb()

DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "sqlServerQuery"
Set q = db.CreateQueryDef"sqlServerQuery"


q.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=myDSN;UID=myUser;PWD=myPassword"

queryString = "SELECT something FROM mySQLServertable"

q.SQL = queryString
q.ReturnsRecords = True
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to call a saved query rather than copying the query string?

Comment: So you want to run a saved query but pass the login credentials? Yes, have the code I showed build the pass through query with your credentials then have your saved query run against that.

Comment: Why do you want to want to pass the credentials in VBA?

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to automate a report to have it sent out every morning  but would get prompted for login credentials.

Comment: I see. It may be more convenient to setup a linked table to SQL Server that has your credentials saved or is a trusted connection like @KKloke suggested.

Comment: @Halen-Lakes if our answers are helpful, please mark the question as answered and upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an ADO connection, you can connect to the SQL Server database with an ODBC connection string:

```
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=[My Server];Database=[My Database];User Id=[My Username];Password=[My Password];"

    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [My Table]"
    cmd.Execute

    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.Open cmd
```

This will load the results of the "SELECT * from [My Table]" query into a recordset called rst.  If you have access to the SQL Server database via your AD credentials, you can use a trusted connection:

```
conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=[My Server];Database=[My Database];Trusted_Connection=True"
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to call a saved query rather than copying the query string?

Comment: If you're connecting via a file dsn, you could store the password there:  UID=test
PWD=test123